# Native-speaking Spanish radio station or podcast for learning?

Tags: recursos

Scouring TunedIn and Google search results, I've been unable to find a good talk radio station in Spanish. This is not a technical question, but rather a question about where to find the tools I need to improve my Spanish. **If there's a different forum for Foreign Language Learning Tools/Strategies please let me know!**

Otherwise, here are my criteria:

- Can be listened to online (either streaming live or by episode)
- Spoken in 100% Spanish for a Spanish-speaking audience
- Is free

Again, I'm looking for *specific* sources for listening to talk radio or talk show Spanish. For example, a particular TunedIn station or Podcast would do the trick.

---

Busando TunedIn y los resultados de búsqueda de Google, no he sido capaz de encontrar una buena estación de “talk radio”—o sea, un programa de conversación de radio—en español. Esto no es una pregunta técnica, sino más bien una pregunta acerca de dónde encontrar las herramientas que necesito para mejorar mi español. ** Si hay un foro diferente para Herramientas/Estrategias de Aprendizaje de Español, ¡por favor avísenme!**

De lo contrario , aquí están mis criterios :

- Se pueden escuchar en línea (en tiempo real o por episodio)
- Se habla en 100 % español para una audiencia de hispanoparlantes nativos
- Es gratis

Una vez más, busco fuentes específicas para escuchar programas de radio “talk show” en español . Por ejemplo, una estación TunedIn en particular o Podcast lograría lo que se necesita.

Comment: http://www.cadena3.com/radio-en-vivo.asp?programacion=CADENA%203

Comment: http://www.wradio.com.co/player.aspx is one of the most popular radio stations in Colombia. They have a news/talk show every morning that could be a good Spanish practice.

Comment: http://www.vorterix.com/ If you want to hear a very different accent  (Buenos Aires)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some:

Radio stations:

- [Antena3 - La Sexta Radio](http://www.atresplayer.com/radio/) (you need to register)
- [RTVE A la carta Radio](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/live_radio_PopUp.shtml?id=1712486&v=undefined&vp=&lang=es)
- [Cadena SER - TuneIn](http://tunein.com/radio/Cadena-Ser-a38593/)

Live TV:

- [La Sexta Live TV](http://www.atresplayer.com/directos/television/lasexta/)

Podcasts in Spanish:

- [Spanish Podcasts](http://www.spanishpodcast.org/podcasts/)
- [RadioLingua podcasts](http://radiolingua.com/lnd-cbs4-intro/)
- [RNE all radio programs](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/programas/rne/todos/1/)
- [00Podcast.es](http://www.00podcast.es/)

Comment: You should add Cadena SER, the most listened to radio in Spain. You can find most, if not all, of its local stations in TuneIn. I'll link to [Cadena Ser Madrid](http://tunein.com/radio/Cadena-Ser-(Madrid)-1054-s17503/).

Comment: Nice suggestion. Answer edited with your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

[Radio Ambulante](http://radioambulante.org/en/) is an excellent podcast on Latin American culture and history. Truly interesting, well researched stories.

Answer (score 1):

RNE is the Spanish public radio network, a part of Radiotelevisión Española (RTVE), the corporation responsible for managing national public-service broadcasting in Spain. There are 6 (IMHO high quality) free channels available online and via podcast ("a la carta"). There is a huge amount of programs availables covering almost any topic or music style.

Like its television broadcasting sister organisation, TVE, Radio Nacional is wholly financed by public funds and does not air commercials in its programming.

Here is an abstract from english wikipedia with updated links (*):

- [**Radio Nacional**](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-nacional) (previously Radio 1) – Generalist channel with a broad
  spectrum of mostly speech-based programming.
- [**Radio Clásica**](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-clasica) (previously Radio 2) – Concerts and classical music in
  general.
- [**Radio 3**](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-3) – RNE's "youth station", concentrating on pop, rock, world
  music, folk, and allied cultural events.
- [**Radio 4**](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-4) – Regional broadcasting in the Catalan language.
- [**Radio 5**](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-5) – 24-hour news.
- [**Radio Exterior de España**](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-exterior) – International broadcasting service on
  short wave, with an audience of 80 million listeners (surpassed only
  by the BBC and Vatican Radio). This station is also transmitted via
  DAB for Spain and by satellite. Transmissions are in Spanish, French,
  Arabic, Ladino, Portuguese, Russian and English.

Note that RTVE/RNE are from Spain. Maybe you find interesting hearing other "flavors". I'm pretty sure there are public radio networks in almost every spanish-spoken country. Could somebody comment or expand the list?.

(*) *I'm, sorry, I have not reputation enough to post more than two links.*

Update: Ya puedo, links actualizados.

Comment: Aunque tengas poca reputación creo que puedes comentar en tu propia respuesta. Inténtalo y coloca los enlaces en comentarios.

Comment: Vamos a intentarlo:
 - [**Radio Nacional**][1] 
 - [**Radio Clásica**][2] 
 - [**Radio 3**][3] 
 - [**Radio 4**][4] 
 - [**Radio 5**][5] 
 - [**Radio Exterior de España**][6] ] 

  [1]: http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-nacional
  [2]: http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-clasica
  [3]: http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-3
  [4]: http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-4
  [5]: http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-5
  [6]: http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/rne/radio-exterior

Answer (score 0):

I'm Spanish and use this page to listen spanish radio stations.

[Emisora.org.es](http://www.emisora.org.es/)